# How can I set up a bluetooth PAN connection with a Raspberry Pi and an iPod?

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I have tried following this tutorial: [How to enable PAN on Raspberry](http://m-jorgensen.dk/how-to-enable-pan-on-raspberry/)

When I try this command:

```
sudo pand –connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -n
```

I get the error:

```
pand[4035]: Bluetooth PAN daemon version 4.99 
pand[4035]: Connecting to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
pand[4035]: Connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx failed. Connection refused(111)
```

I have tried the following so my *iPod* is trusted by my *Raspberry Pi.*

```
> sudo bluez-test-device trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx yes
```

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered the 'Bluetooth Device Manager' in Menu->Preferences? Try Devices->select device and right click->Setup->Connect group network.

Answer (score 22):

Here's how you can setup a bluetooth pan on Raspbian.

This answer uses systemd/networkd but you could do something similar with an interfaces file and dnsmasq if you wanted.

Run:

`sudo apt-get install bluez-tools`

Create the following files:

*/etc/systemd/network/pan0.netdev*

```
[NetDev]
Name=pan0
Kind=bridge
```

*/etc/systemd/network/pan0.network*

```
[Match]
Name=pan0

[Network]
Address=172.20.1.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
```

*/etc/systemd/system/bt-agent.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth Auth Agent

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bt-agent -c NoInputNoOutput
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*/etc/systemd/system/bt-network.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth NEP PAN
After=pan0.network

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bt-network -s nap pan0
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable bt-agent
sudo systemctl enable bt-network
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start bt-agent
sudo systemctl start bt-network
```

Finally to pair, run:

`sudo bt-adapter --set Discoverable 1`

Then, on the other device pair it and connect the network. Hopefully everything should just work after that.

Also note: currently, if you are running Raspbian Stretch, you will need an updated btuart script to workaround the issue [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/860).

Comment: I didn't need to use the updated btuart script as my bluetooth address wasn't 'weird' on my RPi 3 using Stretch

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm having some trouble getting the PAN to work over Mini UART, though. Posted a new question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99997/mini-uart-bluetooth-pan-on-pi-zero-w

Comment: hi trying to make this work on RPi4.  Run all those commands. paired the devices.  i now want to connect to my web server hosted on rpi. what do.can i type into my browser to do that?

Comment: As far as I understand, this is to share the Internet Connection the Pi has, no the other way around. The DHCP is set on Pi, not on the other device. I wanna do the reverse, connect to a PAN server, like my mobile.