# bluetooth transfer speed 10x slower than wifi

Tags: pi-3, wifi, bluetooth

I run a mqtt server on raspberry pi 3B together with a mqtt client on android handset. A data sequence will be transferred from the server to the client by TCP.

I enabled ip over bluetooth on raspberry pi 3B following the answer of [How can I set up a bluetooth PAN connection with a Raspberry Pi and an iPod?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/how-can-i-set-up-a-bluetooth-pan-connection-with-a-raspberry-pi-and-an-ipod)

However, the transfer speed is much slower than wifi connection. It took about 5 seconds to transfer a length 8192 integer sequence, while wifi costs about 0.5 seconds.

This is how I implemented mqtt TCP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165209/mqtt-transfer-speed-much-slower-when-data-size-increases-on-tcp.

I cut off the wifi power with `rfkill block wifi`, and move the handset right next to raspberry pi, which improve the transfer speed a little. But it still takes about 3 seconds to transfer a length 8192 integer sequence.

I am wondering whether the setup of ip over bluetooth is not right, or something else I have missed.

Please advise, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to wonder why my WiFi was slow instead of Bluetooth. Just as a rough figure of merit, WiFi could be **300x** faster than Bluetooth ([ref](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Bluetooth_vs_Wifi)).

And with respect to, `3 seconds to transfer a length 8192 integer sequence`:

- The [ref](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Bluetooth_vs_Wifi) indicates Bluetooth data rates can be as much as 2.1 Mbps, but also says there's a 200 msec **latency**. Could you be incurring multiple latencies due to the way in which you're transferring things?
- What exactly is a is a `length 8192 integer sequence`... how many bits is that?

I'm afraid this is not really an answer, but more of a reminder that measurement of transfer rates, and comparison to published specifications is an endeavor that requires a fair amount of specificity. 3 seconds seems a bit long to me also, but your question may be lacking enough detail to allow anyone to offer a reasoned opinion opinion, much less a specific answer.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I gave up this ip over bluetooth idea, and instead setting up a wifi Access Point following the below weblink https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-an-access-point/all

Comment: @exds75: Apologies! Did not mean to discourage you, but the question couldn't be answered (well) as it's written, and so I was only trying to prod you into thinking through it a bit more. Before you get too far along with the sparkfun video, you should [check out Ingo's Q&A here on this site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way/88234#88234). [He's a good man - and thorough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHt2szt8pRs)  :)