# Mini UART Bluetooth PAN on Pi Zero W

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, uart, serial-console

I followed [these instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/71587/80858) to enable a Bluetooth PAN on my Raspberry Pi Zero W. It mostly works fine, but it occupies a serial port. I need UART (mounted at `/dev/ttyAMA0`) for serial communications, so I switched Bluetooth to Mini UART, which has to run at a lower baud rate.

After switching Bluetooth to Mini UART by putting `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` in `/boot/config.txt` and disabling the kernel console, `hcitool dev` unfortunately shows an empty list of devices and the Bluetooth PAN stops working.

`/boot/cmdline.txt` looks like this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=PARTUUID=855bb810-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

And the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/proc/device-tree/soc/gpio@7e200000/bt_pins/brcm,pins
Requires=dev-serial1.device
After=dev-serial1.device

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/btuart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I looked inside `/usr/bin/btuart`, and it seems to make provision for `/dev/serial1`, but maybe it needs to told explicitly to use /dev/ttyS0 (or ttyS1). Do I need to tell it explicitly to use a different serial port?

How do I get Bluetooth PAN working over Mini UART?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `core_freq=250` to `/boot/config.txt` solves the problem by downclocking the GPU core frequency. I don't understand why this affects Bluetooth yet, but PAN over MiniUART is stable now.

Comment: The reason for this is the mini-uart's baudrate is a fixed proportion of the core clock frequency. For more information read:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md